# Nonexistent branch in ls-remote output

Tags: git

I have a branch that appears in my "git ls-remote" output, but it's not mentioned anywhere under .git/refs, .git/logs, not in the config, only has a brief mention under .git/logs/HEAD and doesn't otherwise appear in plaintext anywhere else under .git/, and is not listed as a branch in Github (the remote).

It's mystifying. Where else could this branch be recorded?

I tried recreating the branch, pushing, and then pruning from both sides, but it didn't seem to affect it. This is the ls-remote output, for reference. It's the bottom entry.

```
e00b6910a899a378c876b9af9238e0f048db30d8    HEAD
95bd66fe02d3fc532c479e364b118b1623f956ba    refs/heads/dustin/debug_chromium
8a4031f8d9493f2cbdeef8c3674a65b8803360f7    refs/heads/dustin/pricing_and_availability_pp
e00b6910a899a378c876b9af9238e0f048db30d8    refs/heads/master
c71f62939e69205b4b052a5094397c0bf8c270dc    refs/remotes/origin/dustin/redis_based_classifier
```

Comment: It could be in `.git/packed-refs`.

Comment: It would've shown up in the grep, but mentioned that there were no results in the grep save one hit. I've confirmed that it's not there.

Comment: `refs/remotes/origin/*` is not expected in a remote repository unless the remote repository was cloned/fetched from another repository. It's normal that it does not exist in your current repository because this ref has nothing to do with the local repository at all. Say the local repository is A and it was cloned from B, and B was cloned from C. `refs/remotes/origin/dustin/redis_based_classifier` is a mapping tie between B and C. By default, when you clone B to A, only `refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*` are fetched.

Comment: If that knowledge were stored locally, would you have an educated guess where that would be?

Comment: It could be packed in `.git/packed-refs` or be a file under `.git/refs`, depending on the way it is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ElpieKay said in its comment : this ref is not under `refs/heads` or `refs/tags`, so it won't be stored in your local repo (in your configuration, check the refspecs listed as `fetch = ...` values under your `[remote "origin"]` section).

It is probably an artefact of some previous repo, or some previous push command where someone specified `origin/dustin/redis_based_classifier` as the ref to push.

---

If you want to get a local branch pointing to that commit : you can specify an explicit refspec with `git fetch` :

```
# this will store it in a local branch named 'dustin/redis_based_classifier' :
git fetch origin refs/remotes/origin/dustin/redis_based_classifier:refs/heads/dustin/redis_based_classifier
```

If you want to delete that ref from the remote, you use `git push -d` and specify its full name :

```
git push origin -d refs/remotes/origin/dustin/redis_based_classifier
```

Comment: Yeah. That did it, though it's still unclear whether that information was local (and where) or remote, since there was no actual trace of it anywhere. Nor was it in the config, as mentioned above.